# Upgrade v2.2 to v2.3.4.1 after getting Admin Error in Oscommerce

Tags: php, ssl, oscommerce

I have upgraded OSCommerce v2.2 to v2.3.4.1 after the front store completely works. But admin getting errors like below:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant ENABLE_SSL - assumed 'ENABLE_SSL'
> (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
> /home/inceptio/public_html/curtispayments/test-os/admin/includes/functions/html_output.php
> on line 14
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /home/inceptio/public_html/curtispayments/test-os/admin/includes/functions/html_output.php:14)
> in
> /home/inceptio/public_html/curtispayments/test-os/admin/includes/functions/general.php
> on line 25

I have already SSL enabled on my website. also, add the below code in both configure.php files

```
define('ENABLE_SSL', true);
```

When I insert the above code in admin configure.php getting me:

**This page isn’t w﻿orking**

Admin: https://inceptionsystem.com/curtispayments/test-os/admin/

Front: https://inceptionsystem.com/curtispayments/test-os/

How can I solve this? Does anyone suggest for very appreciate?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK easy to find the file and line like this
crate a file in the store root
in bash shell
You must be in the directory above "catalog"
Copy and paste this into the bash shell

```
BA=$(cat <<-ENDBA
#!/bin/bash
file="allcode"
catalog="catalog"
today="\`date -u +\"%Y%m%d%H%M%S\"\`" 
if [ -s "\$file" ]
then 
   echo "File \$file exists and is not empty "
   FILE="\$file_pre_\$today"
   echo "Preserving older allcode File to: \$FILE"
   mv \$file \$FILE
   echo "....creating New \$file file"
else
   FILE="\$file"
   echo " file \$file does not exist, or is empty "
   echo "....creating file \$file"
fi
grep -I  -n  -r "." \$catalog  | egrep  -e ".php*:" -e ".js:" -e ".sql:" -e ".css:" -e ".xml:" -e ".crt:" -e ".ht*:" >\$FILE
ENDBA
)
BL=$(cat <<-ENDBL
#!/bin/bash
if [ \$# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No arguments provided"
    echo -n " Enter Search String "
    read search
    if [ -z "\$search" ]
    then 
        exit 1
    else
        echo " Searching for string \$search "
    fi
else
  search=\$1
  echo " Searching for string \$search " 
fi
cat allcode | egrep -e \$search| egrep  -e ".php*:" >\$search.found 
#cat allcode | egrep -e "\$search"| egrep  -e ".php*:" -e ".js:" -e ".sql:" -e ".css:" -e ".xml:" -e ".crt:" -e ".ht*:">\$search.found
echo -n "Matching Lines Found "; wc -l \$search.found
cat \$search.found | sed -e "s/:.*/:/g" | sort -u>\$search.files
echo -n "Matching Files Found are "; wc -l  \$search.files
#comment out line 7 and un-comment line 8 for looking in all code not just PHP
ENDBL
)
echo -e "$BL" >bl
echo -e "$BA" >ba
sudo chmod u+x ba bl
./ba
#now all  your code is backed up and you can search it
```

Hope I got all the escapes right :(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31057735)